# how to change properties of a different element if another div element is focused in css

Tags: html, css, focus, background-color, pseudo-class

I'm trying to create a square whereas if the square gets clicked the background color of body element gets changed. But the code doesn't seem to work.
Here are the code I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "square" tabindex="1">
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
    .square{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    .square:focus body{
       background-color: yellow;
    }
```

Comment: body is the parent of square, not the other way round. CSS does not let you 'go back up' in the way you would need t do this in the way you have it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JavaScript to do this in the following way:

```js
let sq = document.querySelector('.square');
sq.addEventListener('focus', ()=>{
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
});
```

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="square" tabindex="1">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### HERE WE GO!

---

**use this in script:**

function myFunction() {
document.body.style.backgroundColor= "yellow";

**It will change pre-decided color to yellow**

---

**do not forget to call this fuction via *button or link***

---

**customize button/link as you want**

---

**Check sample code below ---- Run snippet code**

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--code by alok shukla-->
<html>

  <body style="background-color: red;">

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Change Color</button>

  <script>
  function myFunction() {   
  document.body.style.backgroundColor= "yellow";
  }
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you wanted? I have added [onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor ='yellow'] after the body tag. I hope it works for you!

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.square:focus body {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="square" tabindex="1" onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor ='yellow'"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This probably won't work because I'm guessing they need to reverse the color when the user clicks away or focuses on another element. One note, just update your code to add "onclick" to the `square` div not on the body. Because they want color to change when clicking on the square not on the body.

Comment: Thank you @VakoShvili. I have added to the square div but not sure how many edits I have made before posting this. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

As @AHaworth pointed out it's not possible to go up in the hierarchy to select the parent element.

Probably the best solution is to use JavaScript as answered by Master Yushi.

However, there's sort of a CSS-only solution if you change a layout a bit. Using the [general sibling combinator](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) it's possible to select a sibling element if it comes somewhere after the `.square` in HTML. So you can add a new `div` to wrap the entire page inside it. And make `.square` `position: absolute;` and position it wherever you need it. It might or might not work for you depending on the page layout you need.

Here's a demo:

```css
    .square{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    .bg {
      background-color: blue;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    .square:focus ~ .bg {
       background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "square" tabindex="1">click me</div>
  <div class="bg"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, one way of doing it is through JQuery. Firstly add JQuery plugin to your HTML code and then add this code to your script.

```
$(".square").click(function(){
    $("body").css("background-color", "yellow")
});
```